# Integrate a js in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to integrate this script to my website homepage and i don't know how. I tried to integrate code to function.php but it doesn't work.

The script :

```
(function(){
var PleaseRotate = {},
    currentOrientation = null,
    isMobile = /Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent),
    init = false;

var options = {
    startOnPageLoad: true,
    onHide: function(){},
    onShow: function(){},
    forcePortrait: false,
    message: "Please Rotate Your Device",
    subMessage: "(or click to continue)",
    allowClickBypass: true,
    onlyMobile: true,
    zIndex: 1000,
    iconNode: null
};

var cssRules = [
   "#pleaserotate-graphic { margin-left: 50px; width: 200px; animation: pleaserotateframes ease 2s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; transform-origin: 50% 50%; -webkit-animation: pleaserotateframes ease 2s; -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%; -moz-animation: pleaserotateframes ease 2s; -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite; -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%; -ms-animation: pleaserotateframes ease 2s; -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite; -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%; }",
    "#pleaserotate-backdrop { background-color: white; top: 0; left: 0; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; }",
    "#pleaserotate-container { width: 300px; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-right: -50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }",
    "#pleaserotate-message { margin-top: 20px; font-size: 1.3em; text-align: center; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase }",
    "#pleaserotate-message small { opacity: .5; display: block; font-size: .6em}"
];

var cssKeyframeRules = [
    "pleaserotateframes{ 0% { transform:  rotate(0deg) ; -moz-transform:  rotate(0deg) ;-webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) ;-ms-transform:  rotate(0deg) ;} 49% { transform:  rotate(-90deg) ;-moz-transform:  rotate(-90deg) ;-webkit-transform:  rotate(-90deg) ; -ms-transform:  rotate(-90deg) ;  } 100% { transform:  rotate(90deg) ;-moz-transform:  rotate(-90deg) ;-webkit-transform:  rotate(-90deg) ; -ms-transform:  rotate(-90deg) ;  } }",
];

/* private functions */

function overrideOptions(updates){
    var prop;
    for (var prop in updates){
        options[prop] = updates[prop];
    }
}

function setBodyClass(state){
    if(document.documentElement){
        document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)pleaserotate-\S*/g , '' );
        document.documentElement.className += " pleaserotate-" + state;
    }
}

function addRules(sheet){

    var i;

    for(i = 0; i< cssRules.length; i++){
        sheet.insertRule(cssRules[i], 0);
    }

    sheet.insertRule("#pleaserotate-backdrop { z-index: " + options.zIndex + "}", 0);

    if(options.allowClickBypass){
        sheet.insertRule("#pleaserotate-backdrop { cursor: pointer }", 0);
    }

    if(options.forcePortrait){
        sheet.insertRule("#pleaserotate-backdrop { -webkit-transform-origin: 50% }", 0);

    }

    for(i = 0; i< cssKeyframeRules.length; i++){
        if (CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE) { // WebKit
            sheet.insertRule("@-webkit-keyframes " + cssKeyframeRules[i], 0);
        }
        else if (CSSRule.MOZ_KEYFRAMES_RULE) { // Mozilla
            sheet.insertRule("@-moz-keyframes " + cssKeyframeRules[i], 0);
        }
        else if (CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE) { // W3C
            sheet.insertRule("@keyframes " + cssKeyframeRules[i], 0);
        }
    }

}

function createStyleSheet(){
    var style = document.createElement("style");
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode("")); // I'm told we need this hack... something to do with safari but I don't feel like checking for sure
    document.head.insertBefore(style, document.head.firstChild);
    addRules(style.sheet);
}

function createElements(){
    var backdrop = document.createElement("div"),
        container = document.createElement("div"),
        message = document.createElement("div"),
        subMessage = document.createElement("small");

    backdrop.setAttribute("id", "pleaserotate-backdrop");
    container.setAttribute("id", "pleaserotate-container");
    message.setAttribute("id", "pleaserotate-message");

    backdrop.appendChild(container);

    if(options.iconNode !== null){
        container.appendChild(options.iconNode);
    } else {
        container.appendChild(createPhoneSVG());
    }

    container.appendChild(message);
    message.appendChild(document.createTextNode(options.message));
    subMessage.appendChild(document.createTextNode(options.subMessage));

    message.appendChild(subMessage);

    document.body.appendChild(backdrop);

}

function createPhoneSVG(){
    var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg');
    svg.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/','xmlns:xlink','http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
    svg.setAttribute('id','pleaserotate-graphic');
    svg.setAttribute('viewBox','0 0 250 250');

    var group = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','g');
    group.setAttribute('id','pleaserotate-graphic-path');

    if(options.forcePortrait){
        group.setAttribute('transform','rotate(-90 125 125)');
    }

    var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
    path.setAttribute('d', 'M190.5,221.3c0,8.3-6.8,15-15,15H80.2c-8.3,0-15-6.8-15-15V28.7c0-8.3,6.8-15,15-15h95.3c8.3,0,15,6.8,15,15V221.3z' +
        'M74.4,33.5l-0.1,139.2c0,8.3,0,17.9,0,21.5c0,3.6,0,6.9,0,7.3c0,0.5,0.2,0.8,0.4,0.8s7.2,0,15.4,0h75.6c8.3,0,15.1,0,15.2,0' + 
        's0.2-6.8,0.2-15V33.5c0-2.6-1-5-2.6-6.5c-1.3-1.3-3-2.1-4.9-2.1H81.9c-2.7,0-5,1.6-6.3,4C74.9,30.2,74.4,31.8,74.4,33.5z' + 
        'M127.7,207c-5.4,0-9.8,5.1-9.8,11.3s4.4,11.3,9.8,11.3s9.8-5.1,9.8-11.3S133.2,207,127.7,207z');
    svg.appendChild(group);
    group.appendChild(path);

    return svg;
}

function setVisibility(visible){
    var backdropElement = document.getElementById("pleaserotate-backdrop");

    if(visible){
        if(backdropElement){
            backdropElement.style["display"] = "block";
        }
    } else {
        if(backdropElement){
            backdropElement.style["display"] = "none";

        }
    }
}

function orientationChanged(){
    var triggerOn = currentOrientation && !options.forcePortrait || !currentOrientation && options.forcePortrait,
        propogate;

    if(triggerOn){
        propogate = options.onShow();
        setBodyClass("showing");
    } else {
        propogate = options.onHide();
        setBodyClass("hiding");
    }


    if(propogate !== undefined && !propogate){
        return;
    }

    PleaseRotate.Showing = triggerOn;

    setVisibility(triggerOn);

}

function isPortrait(){
    return ( window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight);
}

function checkOrientationChange(){
    if(!isMobile && options.onlyMobile){
        if(!init){
            init = true;
            setVisibility(false);
            setBodyClass("hiding");
            options.onHide(); // run this exactly once if not mobile
        }
        return;
    }

    if(currentOrientation !== isPortrait()){
        currentOrientation = isPortrait();
        orientationChanged();
    }
}

/* public functions */

PleaseRotate.start = function(opts){
    if(!document.body){
        window.addEventListener('load', PleaseRotate.start.bind(null, opts), false);
        return;
    }

    if(opts){
        overrideOptions(opts);
    }

    createStyleSheet();
    createElements();
    checkOrientationChange();
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', checkOrientationChange, false );

    if(options.allowClickBypass){
        document.getElementById("pleaserotate-backdrop").addEventListener("click", function(){
            var propogate = options.onHide();
            setBodyClass("hiding");
            PleaseRotate.Showing = false;

            if(propogate === undefined || propogate){
                setVisibility(false);
            }
        });
    }
}

PleaseRotate.stop = function(){
    window.removeEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

PleaseRotate.onShow = function(fn){
    options.onShow = fn;

    if(init){
        // if we have already been initialized, force a check
        init = false;
        currentOrientation = null;
        checkOrientationChange();
    }
};

PleaseRotate.onHide = function(fn){
    options.onHide = fn;

    if(init){
        // if we have already been initialized, force a check so that onHide gets called
        currentOrientation = null;
        init = false;
        checkOrientationChange();
    }
};

PleaseRotate.Showing = false;

/* plumbing to support AMD, CommonJS, or Globals */

if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    setBodyClass("initialized");
    define(['PleaseRotate'], function() {
        return PleaseRotate;
    });
} else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    setBodyClass("initialized");
    module.exports = PleaseRotate;
} else {
    setBodyClass("initialized");
    window.PleaseRotate = PleaseRotate;
    overrideOptions(window.PleaseRotateOptions);

    if (options.startOnPageLoad) {
        PleaseRotate.start();
    }
}

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the JavaScript to be on the homepage only, you can do this:

```
function wpdocs_scripts_method() {
  if ( is_home() ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js', false ) );
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_scripts_method' );
```

Create a JavaScript file, and then place your code in there. Then replace the path and filename in the function above, and the script should be included on the homepage of your website. This code snippet should be placed in your functions.php file.

To read more: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/